# Passing an array's elements as arguments to a method

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments

```
class Test
  def initialize(*args)
    print "I got #{args.length} arguments!"
  end
end

arguments = ["Hello",100,30]

Test.new(arguments)
```

There, `Test` is only receiving one argument (an array). Would it be possible to pass the array's elements as the arguments for `Test` instead? So that `Test`'s constructor identifies three arguments instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [splat operator](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/), `*`.

```
class Test
  def initialize(*args)
    print "I got #{args.length} arguments!"
  end
end

arguments = ["Hello",100,30]

Test.new(*arguments)
```

Answer (score 1):

Splat them: `Test.new(*arguments)`